# Critical error but refresh fixes it

Tags: errors, server

I'm experiencing an intermittent issue where the "critical error" page is displayed but once you refresh the page it's working like normal. There is no information displayed when I have debug turned on and no email is received. I've checked the error log and there are no entries in there. Where else can I check to see what is going on?

The website is hosted on a digitalocean droplet (1 vCPU, 2GB memory, 25GB SSD).

Fixes that I've tried:
- Adding a swapfile
- Running apache2buddy script and reducing MaxRequestWorkers
- IP blocking someone trying to use the xmlrpc exploit (before I did this, I would get the database connection could not be established error and had to reboot the droplet for the website to work again)

Comment: For details debug, you may try `define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', '/volumes/some-where/wp-errors.log' );` output the log file so that you can read it any time for bug fixing.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by the critical error page? Is this a WP critical error page? Apache? Something else? Which error log are you checking?

Comment: @TomJNowell The WP critical error page. I've checked the apache error log. I've just defined the WP_DEBUG_LOG location so I'll be able to check that if/when the error shows again.

Comment: The Apache error log won't contain PHP errors, just Apache errors. You need to look at the PHP error log ( and enable it if it exists )

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm having the same problem and don't know where to look!